# js code to dynamically set the width and height of the image before using/loading in other areas of the application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am displaying the below div content which has tables,images and some more html elements on the webpage(I'm getting the div content from the data base which i am showing on the webpage).

```
<div class="appDiv">
 <div>  <h1><font color="red"> Title here</font></h1> </div>
<table><tr><th>Header1</th><th>Header2</th></tr><tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr></table>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEBLAEsAAD/2w..............Z0auj5MNqRUIfYT7C/cEhSmGlRdn6/wDrACwSw+eV/u/bvuN0D/TZZTeE8Sdtooj7/wB5Q6C/DTrP/9k=" data-filename='image.png' style='width: 1081.05px; height: 512.635px;'>
</div>
```

I want to use the above mentioned content in other areas of my application, but issue is i need to reduce the width and height of the image due to place restriction.**I want to change the width and height of the image dynamically** **before i use the above code in other parts of my application**.

**js code:**
Below code is called when user is exporting the above div content to other parts, here i need to change the width and height of any of the image shown in the div

```
 function($scope) {

   $scope.loadWebContentInOtherArea= function() {


   }
 }
```

The `<img>` tag shown above doesn't have the class name or the id to set the width and height before loading on other parts of the web page.How can i set dynamically the width and height of the image when it doesn't have any class name or ID assigned to it.
Please see the `<img>` tag, it has defined `style='width: 1081.05px; height: 512.635px;'`

Comment: is it only one <img> tag in the whole application ?  or you are having multiple images ??

Comment: @ManavMandal - The data i'm getting is dyamic, i can have multiple images.

Answer (score 1):

> How can i set dynamically the width and height of the image when it
>   doesn't have any class name or ID assigned to it.

Since you are...

> displaying the below div content

and your `div` has a class, you can call each `div` element and find each `img` element and set the dimensions.

```
var imgEl = document.querySelector('.appDiv img');
imgEl.width = 100;
imgEl.height = 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript Code below should do what you are asking for.

```
var appDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("appDiv");
var img = appDiv[0].getElementsByTagName("img");
img[0].style.width = "100px";
img[0].style.height = "50px";
```

I could have written it in a more condensed way, but I wanted to break it down for you so here it goes.

The first line is selecting that Div with the class "appDiv". If you have more than 1 div with this class it will select them all and save them to an array.

The second line is selecting the img inside of the first instance of a div with the class "appDiv".

If you have multiple instances of this div you can change which div to target by changing the [0] after "appDiv[0]" on the second line.

Remember Javascript Arrays start at 0, so 0 is actually the first instance of your div. 1 would be the second instance and so on.

Now that you have your img saved in the "img" variable the 3rd and 4th lines set the width and height of your image programmatically.

Please let me know if this helps!

Edit, Just to show it this is my code wrapped in for loop to cycle through all the images in the document.

```
var appDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("appDiv");
for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByClassName("appDiv").length;i++){
  var img = appDiv[i].getElementsByTagName("img");
  img[0].style.width = "100px";
  img[0].style.height = "50px";
}
```

The key here is using the "document.getElementsByClassName("appDiv").length" snippet on the second line. This makes the loop go on as many times as a div with this class is found in the document. Hope this helps!

Seeing that the source code of the project has each image contain the class "image-responsive" you could also use this code below.

```
var imagesToResize = document.getElementsByClassName("image-responsive");
     for(i=0;i<imagesToResize.length;i++){
       imagesToResize[i].style.width = "100px";
       imagesToResize[i].style.height = "100px";
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please find the updated plunker demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/o7we6Q00NixwvVkms5EF?p=preview . Please click on export button, div content is exported to PDF and i want to reduce the image width and height when exported to the PDF. It is applying for only first time.I want to apply for all the images exported to the PDF. Do i need to iterate it to apply for all the images?

Comment: For that you should use Josan Iracheta's answer above. His code is the more condensed version I was talking about. It automatically selects all images on your page that are inside of a div with the class "appDiv". If you wanted to use my code you would have to iterate over it for every picture though this can be done with a for loop it's not really necessary unless you want control over certain images to exclude. But considering you want to change all the images Josan's answer is simpler.

Comment: I applied Josan Iracheta solution, but still it is applying for the first itertion only. Please find the demo https://plnkr.co/edit/o7we6Q00NixwvVkms5EF?p=preview . I have iterated the div and i have multiple images but only the first image width is reduced.@YAHsaves

Comment: See my updated answer above. I included my code wrapped in the for loop to cycle through all the pictures of the document.

Comment: Also I looked at Josan's answer too quickly. My apologies. To make his answer work you would have to change "querySelector" to "querySelectorAll" and then cycle through the image elements in a for loop similar to how I did in my answer. That code would be more concise, but I'm writing the code out for you to help you understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: It is not working. Please find the updated link https://plnkr.co/edit/MIcfkS12Ltpv1crqyy61?p=preview .It is showing the error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: Looking at your source code it appears that it's made differently than what you suggested in your original post. There is no "wrapper div" around the images with class "appDiv". However each image does have a class of "image-responsive". So it's easy to apply the same logic to it. See my updated answer above.

Comment: Appreciate your help. But still unfortunately i could not able to make it work. Please find the updated link with your code https://plnkr.co/edit/ozCEvOCYT1MTORDrgZk4?p=preview  and even when clicked on export button, the content on the webpage is changing one on other,,@YAHsaves

Comment: In your code on the updated plnkr link you are trying to select the wrong class. Open the script.js file and on line 17 change "myDivClass" with "image-responsive".

Comment: Please find the updated demo https://plnkr.co/edit/qcoAe9x80zojRTX4g4Aw?p=preview . Two things i noticed, first issue is it is only applying the width and height for the first image inside the div. I may have multiple images as shown in the link as the data is dynamic for me, i have to apply width and height changes for all the images present in the div.  Second issue is when i click on export button the first image width and height also changing accordingly on the webpage as we applied in js code.@YAHsaves